# Program compiles and executes but an unreasonably large number is output as the maximum. How can a long double be displayed?

Tags: c++

So I got this program to run, but now any numbers that I input come out as really large numerals. Do I need to add a header for math computation? Or is there something like with C, a printf function for C++?

```
#include <iostream>                                                     // Necessary 
using namespace std;
#define mMaxOf2(max, min) ((max) > (min) ? (max) : (min))
#define mMaxOf3(Min, Mid, Max)\
{\
     mMaxOf2(mMaxOf2((Min), (Mid)),(Max))\
}

int main()
{
    double primary;
    double secondary;
    double tertiary;
    long double maximum = mMaxOf3(primary, secondary, tertiary);

    cout << "Please enter three numbers: ";
    cin >> primary >> secondary >> tertiary;
    cout << "The maximum of " << primary << " " << secondary << " " << tertiary;
    cout << " using mMaxOf3 is " << maximum;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, your `max` macros are unsafe because they evaluate their arguments more than once. You should use plain functions (or perhaps function templates) instead - or use `std::max`.

Comment: Aside: Mat's right in that macros should be avoided here.  But, for when you do need macros, a small point: you'd be better off without the `{` and `}` in your `mMaxOf3` substitution - that will work for your exact current usage, but prevents you using maximums inside expressions (for example `mMaxOf3(a,b,c) + 1` might resolve to `{ 3 } + 1` which is a syntax error, not `4`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are computing `maximum` before you get the user's input. Rearrange your code like this:

```
    double primary;
    double secondary;
    double tertiary;
    long double maximum;

    cout << "Please enter three numbers: ";
    cin >> primary >> secondary >> tertiary;

    maximum = mMaxOf3(primary, secondary, tertiary);

    cout << "The maximum of " << primary << " " << secondary << " " << tertiary;
    cout << " using mMaxOf3 is " << maximum;
```

Always remember that code is executed **sequentially**, or you may say **line-by-line**. For C++, any changes to variables affect the behavior of later instructions using those modified variables. In your case, you computed `maximum` first *before* you have properly set the values of `primary`, `secondary` and `tertiary` which are needed in `mMaxOf3`.

As a note, it is completely OK to have `primary`, `secondary`, `tertiary` and `maximum` have uninitialized values in the case of your program.

Comment: Wow. Good to know I am still making newbie mistakes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1728737 It happens sometimes. Just remember one rule in programming: don't let the syntax (or the language) limit your creativity.

Answer (score 1):

This: `long double maximum = mMaxOf3(primary, secondary, tertiary);` needs to go just after `cin >> primary >> secondary >> tertiary;`

The problem you are having is that you are accessing uninitialized variables. You need to access them after you have read them in.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the maximum before the cin statement has set the values of primary, secondary and tertiary.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized 'primary', `secondary` or `tertiary` before your call to `mMaxOf3` so the numbers contain garbage values, hence you get garbage answers. You need to calculate the maximum after inputting the numbers. Also, have a look at [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) as a replacement for your macros